# Dictionary/key word unpacking - must be strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I have created a function

```
>>> fun(a,b,c):
  print(a,b,c)
```

Which I can pass a list to, say `[1,2,3]` by unpacking and we have

```
>>> fun(*[1,2,3])

1, 2, 3
```

or I can pass a dictionary `d = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}`

```
>>> fun(*d)
1, 2, 3
```

However, I experience a problem when I attempt to unpack the keyword arguments

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: fun() keywords must be strings
```

and when I reverse the values and the keys  `d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}`

```
>>> fun(**d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: fun() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

So, two questions: Why does python only allow strings to be keyword arguments (or have I made a mistake)? And why, do I get an unexpected keyword argument when what it's referencing seems clear?

Comment: because you defined your function to take 3 keyword arguments and the arguments were `a`, `b`, and `c`. When you unpack the first dict, its equivalent to calling `fun(1=a, 2=b, 3=c)` which is invalid syntax because you can't have integers as keywords

Comment: Why am I not able to have integers as keywords? Nevermind, upon further thought it is immediately clear what the problem is.

Comment: Defining `d = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}` and doing `fun(*d)` is equivalent to `fun(1,2,3)` similarly defining `d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}` and doing `fun(**d)` is equivalent to `fun(a=1, b=2, c=3)` So `d = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}` and `fun(**d)` is equivalent to `fun(1=a, 2=b, 3=c)` which cannot be valid

Comment: Defining ```d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}``` then should yield ```fun(**d)``` as equivalent to ```fun(a=1,b=2,c=3)``` so why do I get an unexpected keyword arugment 'a' TypeError?

Comment: Check the new dupe I added,